# How can a user add a new field to a table by creating a new attribute

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, attributes

I'm new to Core Data and I got stuck at this part of my xCode project.

I have created a core data entity "Person" and this entity has the following attributes:

- name;
- age;
- birthday;
- address;

and this attributes are getting displayed in a tableview. So far so good.

My problem is that I want the table to have an **"Add Field"** or **"Add Row"** cell so when the user wants to add more information in addition to these already created attributes he just clicks the cell and chooses the field name and type.

For example if he wants the person's "phone number" in the detail view of the table he names the new field "phone number" and chooses its type "number". Then he has an extra field where he can add the person's phone number.

How can I do this in core data? Is there a way for a user to manually add a new attribute to an entity and choosing its format? What is the best approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do exactly what you want with Core Data. Core Data can't change structure except if you make a new version of your design, but you do that in xcode.

But you can easily add another table called f.ex. information, which links to the person single connection and has the person linking back many to the information table.

This way, you can add as many fields and values as you want, of course all the extra fields you add would follow the same person, so if you want to use cellPhone field, you must add that to all.

I would recommend that you use direct SQL, and don't use Core Data. Core Data is not a database, it is an object store, and when you get better at iOS development, you will understand the difference, it is much bigger than  you might think at first.

There is an excellent high level library for SQLite, called FMDB, you can find it on github here : https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Here you can do direct SQL queries like "Alter Table" and more on the fly, though what you are after isn't very simple, it could be real fun project to do.

Good luck with this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is directly possible in Core Data because its purpose is object persistence and you can't add new properties to objects dynamically.  It could be faked to some degree using a to-many relationship to an "extra property" entity that had `name`, `value` (as string), and `data type` fields.

I believe your best option would be using SQLite in order to modify the table structure on the fly.  (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

Answer (score 0):

My last company did something like this, but its not trivial. I don't have access to the code so this is more or less going to be from memory.

- you provide transformable property in your entity (which will be a dictionary)
- the model object has to provide the getter and setter for this that in turn drive the primitive methods to set/get an attribute
- you provide a getter/setter along the lines of -objectForKey and -setObject forKey, which read and write values
- when you are told to 'fault', you update the dictionary in the entity

In summary, maintain a dictionary of key value pairs. Perhaps you maintain a shadow dictionary that gets initialized and updated as needed. Its been around 4 years since I last saw this code so a little fuzzy on it. But you should get the idea. It was like magic - you can arbitrarily set any key/value pair (assuming string keys and NSCoding compliant values), and can always ask for the keys by asking the dictionary for its current set of keys.